# PHP encoding utf-8 with php explode

Tags: php, utf-8

After explotion, i get a lot of unreadable symbols.

```
<?php
$lines = file("dazninis.txt");
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    if($line_num > 1) {
        $arr = explode("\t", $line);
        echo trim((string)$arr[0]), trim((string)$arr[1]), trim((string)$arr[2]), trim((string)$arr[3]);
    }
}
?>
```

I got that:

```
aisiai0-�j�1 19-21-er1-eri�1 1922922-�j�2 1927-asis1 aisissktv1930-�j�2 1933-assktv1933-aisiais1 1937-1940-assktv1937-1940-aisiais1 1940-assktv1940-aisiais2 1941-assktv1941-aisiais1 1944-assktv1944-aisiais1 1944-assktv1944-�j�1 1945-assktv1945-aisiais1 1945-assktv1945-�j�2 1947-assktv1947-aisiais1 1948-1961-assktv1948-1961-�j�1 1948-assktv1948-j�1 1950-assktv1950-aisiais2 1951-assktv1951-ieji1 1951-assktv1951-uosius1 1953-assktv1953-aisiais1 1958-assktv1958-aisiais1 1962-assktv1962-aisiais1 1966-assktv1966-ieji1 1967-assktv1967-ieji1 1967-assktv1967-�j�1 1969-assktv1969-�j�1 1970-assktv1970-�j�1 1971-assktv1971-aisiais2 1972-assktv1972-aisiais1 1973-assktv1973-aisiais1 1973-assktv1973-�j�1 1974-assktv1974-aisiais1 1975-assktv1975-aisiais1 1975-assktv1975-�j�1 1978-assktv1987-�j�1 1979-assktv1979-�j�2 1980-assktv1980-aisiais1 1981-assktv1981-asiais1 1983-assktv1983-�j�1 1984-assktv1984-aisiais2 1985-assktv1985-aisiais2 1985-assktv1985-ieji1 1985-assktv1985-�j�1 1987-1988-assktv1987-1988-aisiais1 1987-assktv1987-aisiais1 1987-assktv1987-�j�1 1988-assktv1988-aisiais1 1988-assktv1988-�j�1
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Set everything and I mean everything (`A to Z`) to UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend to add this at the beginning of your code

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`